# How to simplify $\sqrt{\tan^2 x + \cot^2x }$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to simplify :

$$\sqrt{\tan ^2 x + \cot  ^2x }$$

the option are :

(i) $ \tan  x \cdot \sin  x$

(ii) $\sin  x \cdot \cos  x $

(iii) $ \sec  x \cdot \csc x  $

(iv) $ \frac{1}{\tan  x - \cot   x}$

(v) $ \csc^2 x - \sec ^2 x$

My approach :

Since $\tan  x = \frac{\sin  x}{\cos  x}$ and $\cot  x = \frac{\cos  x}{\sin  x}$,

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\tan ^2 x + \cot  ^2x } &= \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^2 x}{\cos ^2 x} + \frac{\cos ^2 x}{\sin ^2 x}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^4 x + \cos ^4 x}{\sin ^2 x \cdot \cos ^2 x} }\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(\sin ^2 x + \cos ^2 x)^2 - 2 \sin  x \cdot \cos  x}{\sin ^2 x \cdot \cos ^2 x} }\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1 - 2\sin  x \cdot \cos  x}{\sin ^2 x \cdot \cos ^2 x} }\\
&= \sqrt{\sec ^2 x \cdot \csc^2 x - 2 \sec  x \cdot \csc x}\\
&= \sqrt{\sec  x \cdot \csc x ( \sec  x \cdot \csc x - 2)}\\
\end{align}
$$

from this point, I don't have any idea how should I approach this problem to get another form of this equation available on the option.

Another approach I have in  mind is from changing $\cot   x = \frac{1}{\tan  x}$

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\tan ^2 x + \cot  ^2x } &= \sqrt{\tan ^2 x + \frac{1}{\tan ^2 x}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\tan ^4 x + 1}{\tan ^2 x} }\\
\end{align}
$$

From this point, I don't have any idea.

What am I missing or what approach should you suggest to change the form to the option available on the option?

Comment: Use \tan, \sin and \cos etc. to produce $\tan$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead of $tan$, $sin$ and $cos$ which look bad.

Comment: @Gary thanks for the finishing touches

Comment: The value of the question at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ isn't satisfied anywhere in the options.

Comment: @PCMSE Yeah I plot on GeoGebra I thought maybe I'm missing something
I doubt the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake in one of your steps. You should have

$$\sin^4x + \cos^4x = (\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

This then helps you achieve

$$\sqrt{\sec^2x\csc^2x-2}$$

Other than that, none of the choices are correct (as far as I can tell, the above expression can't be simplified any further).